# Valid price at given date

Tags: sql, date

got a table with dates and prices.

```
Date                  Price
2012-01-01            25
2012-01-05            12
2012-01-10            10
```

Is there some kind of function that lets me find what the current price where at '2012-01-07'? Without me knowing of the other dates.

Pseudoquery: select price where currentprice('2012-01-07')

Thanks!

Comment: What DBMS? Is Date stored as a string or a date datatype?

Comment: does your table have an autoincerement id and a product id? It's important to be able to create the query for you.

Comment: And what is the price for '2012-01-07'? Is it the last price set or is it determined in some other way?

Comment: if there's no date/price value do you assume the last observed price is still valid?

Comment: What *is* the current price on 2012-01-07? 12 - The price set on 2012-01-05? 11.2 - the price set on 2012-01-05 decreased linearly to be 10 on 2012-01-10? Something even stranger? Define your problem.

Comment: @SamDeHaan - It's a standard pattern, it's reasonable to answer based on the assumption that the price doesn't change between date.  It's also reasonable to point out that it's an assumption.  But it *can* be pointed out more nicely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL:

```
select price from your_table 
where date <= '2012-01-07'
order by date desc
limit 1
```

SQL Server:

```
select top 1 price from your_table 
where date <= '2012-01-07'
order by date desc
```

Comment: Man people are helpful here... i turned away and got all those answers... off course it was this simple :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have use of ROW_NUMBER(), and want a generic solution, you need to join on a sub-query.

Get the date you want, then get the data for that date.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  yourTable
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT MAX(yourDate) AS maxDate FROM yourTable WHERE yourDate <= @dateParameter
)
  AS lookup
    ON yourTable.yourDate = lookup.maxDate
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 select price 
 from table1 t 
 where t.date = ( select max(t2.date) 
                  from table1 t2
                  where t2.date <= '2012-01-07' )
```

*Note* this is not the copy&paste answer, as we're not not knowing what is the datatype for your `date` column.

Comment: Put something around your date, unless you really want `<= 2004`